# ReactJS: How to find dependencies, which still use PropTypes via main react package

Tags: reactjs, npm, dependencies, react-proptypes

I have changed my react application (based on meteorJS) to the `prop-types` package, but I'm still getting the warning `Warning: Accessing PropTypes via the main React package is deprecated. Use the prop-types package from npm instead.`

So I think there is any dependency which is still using the 'old' style. But how do I find this dependency?

This is what the console gives me:

```
modules.js?hash=49c6db2db08899db6ed5ab18f5681ac3bb3d8eab:13361 Warning: Accessing PropTypes via the main React package is deprecated. Use the prop-types package from npm instead.
printWarning @ modules.js?hash=49c6db2db08899db6ed5ab18f5681ac3bb3d8eab:13361
warning @ modules.js?hash=49c6db2db08899db6ed5ab18f5681ac3bb3d8eab:13385
get @ modules.js?hash=49c6db2db08899db6ed5ab18f5681ac3bb3d8eab:9932
PropTypes.js @ modules.js?hash=49c6db2db08899db6ed5ab18f5681ac3bb3d8eab:32612
fileEvaluate @ modules-runtime.js?hash=8587d188e038b75ecd27ed2469a52b269e38fb62:343
require @ modules-runtime.js?hash=8587d188e038b75ecd27ed2469a52b269e38fb62:238
index.js @ modules.js?hash=49c6db2db08899db6ed5ab18f5681ac3bb3d8eab:32381
fileEvaluate @ modules-runtime.js?hash=8587d188e038b75ecd27ed2469a52b269e38fb62:343
require @ modules-runtime.js?hash=8587d188e038b75ecd27ed2469a52b269e38fb62:238
main.js @ main.js:1
fileEvaluate @ modules-runtime.js?hash=8587d188e038b75ecd27ed2469a52b269e38fb62:343
require @ modules-runtime.js?hash=8587d188e038b75ecd27ed2469a52b269e38fb62:238
(anonymous) @ app.js?hash=bbc39e8f76f81774071d5c0341cfd78e2baf4ccc:25882
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used simple text search on directory 'node_modules' to search for line that could have old style of importing PropTypes from 'react';

```
grep -R "PropTypes.*'react" node_modules/
```

And with that tool, find the project that is causing warning messages from grep output.